# Extracting a numeric value from string and checking if exists

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the current hash `#link1234`.

I need to check with javascript if:

- the current window.location has an hash
- it's in the form of #link[0-9]+

if all good I have to extract that number..

Is that possibile? (maybe with ereg?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to match a `1` followed by any number of other digits:

```
var res = /#link(1\d*)$/.exec(window.location)
```

Or to match any combination of digits, use this:

```
var res = /#link(\d+)$/.exec(window.location)
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
var res = /#link([0-9]+)$/.exec(window.location)
```

The value of `res` will be `null` if there was no match. Otherwise, `res` will be an array having the matched digits in its second position, which can be referenced like this:

```
res[1] // contains any matched digits
```

Comment: Don't forget to capture the 4 digits.

Comment: sorry it's not only 4 digits. They can be any number starting from 1

Comment: @yes123 - Hrm, OK. The latest version matches at least one digit, starting with 1, followed by any number of other digits

Comment: Can I use ([0-9]+) ? And How can i know if that regex was not matched?

Comment: @yes123 - You might want to update your question to say exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @yes123 - `[0-9]+` is the same as `\d+`. However, in your previous comment, you said the number had to start with `1`.

Comment: @iwburk: sorry I meant any positive number

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible and even more simple than you thought.

### Check if the current window.location has a hash:

```
if (window.location.hash !== "") {
    // a hash exists!
}
```

### Extract number of the hash has the given format:

```
var hash = '#link1234';
var regex = /^#?link([0-9]+)$/i;
var match = regex.exec(hash);
if (match != null) {
    var num = m[1];
}
```

The regexp uses the explicitly defined value "link". You have to adjust that if you use other kind of hashes.

Comment: I think you mean: `var num = match[1]`